# Nginx too many redirects socketio/nodejs

Tags: nginx, websocket, socket.io

Hey so i am using socket io with nodejs and nginx but i cant get my site to work,i am getting into a redirect loop of a single page. I am posting my nginx configuration down here and lets hope we can find the issue..Anyone can help me out on this one? With apache i can open the website but nodejs connection not showing on client side so i am using nginx..

```
upstream nodejs {
      server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
    #
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
    
        root /var/www/html;
    
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
        server_name localhost;
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    
            # With php5-cgi alone:
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
    location /app-socket {
        proxy_pass http://nodejs/socket.io;
        proxy_redirect off;
      }
    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://nodejs/socket.io;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404; 
            #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                #fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```